# Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined Puppeteer Node.js

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm getting into web scraping and I'm very new to DOM, html and CSS and I use Node.js and Puppeteer.
In Chrome console when inspecting a drop down menu I see the tree:

```
<select id="variante" class="form-control" name="attribute_variante" data-attribute_name="attribute_variante" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Scegli un'opzione</option><option value="8 Velocità - Work" class="attached enabled">8 Velocità - Work</option><option value="8 Velocità - Family" class="attached enabled">8 Velocità - Family</option><option value="8 Velocità - Child Pack" class="attached enabled">8 Velocità - Child Pack</option></select>
```

which holds the 4 options and to access them you have to click on a button

```
<i class="flaticon-bottom4"></I>
```

and when one option is selected then two other selectors (variation description and price ) gets values

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap"><div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style=""><div class="woocommerce-variation-description"><p>Versione con cambio interno al mozzo Shimano Nexus a 8 velocità e Child Pack che comprende: cestone posteriore porta bimbi pieghevole, pedane laterali pieghevoli.</p>
</div><div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>1.990,00</bdi></span></span></div><div class="woocommerce-variation-availability"><p class="stock available-on-backorder">Disponibile su ordinazione</p>
</div> </div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled"><div class="quantity"> <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_615a86b1a5562">Bicicapace - Justlong quantità</label> <input type="number" id="quantity_615a86b1a5562" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qtà" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric"></div><div id="wc-stripe-payment-request-wrapper" style="clear:both;padding-top:1.5em;display:none;"><div id="wc-stripe-payment-request-button"> <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. --></div></div><p id="wc-stripe-payment-request-button-separator" style="margin-top:1.5em;text-align:center;display:none;">— OPPURE —</p> <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Aggiungi al carrello</button> <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="19487"> <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="19487"> <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="21306"></div></div>
```

I'm trying to get the 4 options values inside a for loop with

```
var variations = [];


    let loop = document.querySelector('select[class=form-control]').options.length; 
    product['Variations'] = loop ?? 1;
    console.log(loop);

    for (var i = 1; i < loop; i++) {

      let variationtName = document.querySelector('select[class=form-control]').options[i].value;

      
      let select = await page.waitForSelector('select[class=form-control]'); 


      // let select = document.querySelector('select[class=form-control]');
      await select.select(variationtName);
      let variationDescription = document.querySelector('div[class=woocommerce-variation-description] > p').innerText;
      let variationPrice = document.querySelector('div[class=woocommerce-variation-price]').innerText;


      let variant = {

        'Variation name': variantName ?? 'N/A',
        'Variation price': variationPrice ?? 'N/A',
        'Variation description': variationDescription ?? 'N/A'

      }
      variations.push(variant);

    }
```

But I get an error:

```
<pre>Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:33:20<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at runMicrotasks (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at async exports.ingestInventory (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/ingest.controller.js:43:14)</pre>
```

How to pass `page` to the `evaluate` function or should I declare a new page in its body?

Many thanks

Comment: The code is executed in a DOM context so the `page` variable is not valid there. You should be calling that outside of the `evaluate`.

Comment: Are you really using puppeteer? How come `document.querySelector` and `page.waitForSelector` appear in the same context.

Comment: @Eldar ok I see.  So could I as well run the loop outside `evaluate`?

Comment: @Ricky Mo ues I'm using Puppeteer, and you'te right, `page waitFirSelector` is where I get the error. As suggested I should run the loop outside `evaluate` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to approach this should be: Get the options list with `evaluate` method. Using that list create a loop, in that loop select the option and run another evaluate function that returns the variation info :

```js
// this returns all the options
const variationNames = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelector('select[class=form-control]').options).map(({
    value
  }) => value)
);

// the select
const select = await page.waitForSelector('select[class=form-control]');
const variations = [];

for (var i = 1; i < variationNames.length; i++) {
  const variationtName = variationNames[i];
  // wait for selection 
  await select.select(variationtName);
  // evaluate to get the variation info
  const variationInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const variationDescription =
      document.querySelector('div[class=woocommerce-variation-description] > p').innerText;
    const variationPrice = document.querySelector('div[class=woocommerce-variation-price]').innerText;
    const v = {
      price: variationPrice ?? 'N/A',
      description: variationDescription ?? 'N/A'
    }
    return v;
  });
  // populate the array
  variations.push({
    name: variationtName,
    ...variationInfo
  });
}
```

Comment: Absolutely! Many thanks!! I see I was using `evaluate` wrongly..I was in fact calling `const data = await.page.evaluate(() =>{}); ` and inside the function's  body I was getting other data plus running the `for` loop ( first mistake). Also of course getting the variations names into an array with `Array.from().map()` gets me the array..( second mistake ). Apart for an extra `;` in the `=> value);` it run perfectly. Many thanks again. Cheers.